How in depth should a background section on cams in an undergraduate thesis be?
I am writing my thesis on the design and construction of a robot that has a lot of mechanical parts in it. A big part of the project is the 2 cams that I am using and I'm not sure how much I should write about cam analysis in the background section. My plan is to explain the general mechanism and include the equations, with explanation, necessary to analyse the cam. Then I would refer back that background section when I am performing the analysis of my specific cam. This would result in a pretty lengthy section on cams as there is a lot of maths involved, but it is an important part of my thesis.
Should I do this? This is for my undergraduate honours thesis, and I don't think that cam analysis is common knowledge among engineers, especially since I am not a mechanical engineer. Another issue is that almost all of my knowledge of cam analysis comes from the Cam Design Handbook 2004, so there would be very few references in this large section. Is there a better way that I should be doing this?

This is a question for your advisor.
